# Test Automation - CodedUI is unable to differentiate between different controls in the application

Tags: visual-studio-2010, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate - visual c# - codedUI.

I'm putting together some automated testing for a client (smoke testing, regression testing, etc.) however the application I'm trying to do the test automation for isn't being cooperative.
I've automated all of the client's web apps with no issues, but with their desktop application, I can't seem to get any unique identifier between any of the controls.

Here's a sample codedUI recording where I go through a tree structure in the application - I highlight several different items in the list, expand a list, click on an item, browse the window that launches etc.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// SomeRecordedMethod
    /// </summary>
    public void SomeRecordedMethod()
    {
        #region Variable Declarations
        WinTitleBar uINavigatorTitleBar = this.UISomeRandomCompanyWindow.UINavigatorWindow.UINavigatorTitleBar;
        WinEdit uIObjectdescEdit = this.UISomeRandomCompanyWindow.UINavigatorWindow.UIDw_navigatorClient.UIObjectdescEdit;
        WinClient uICalendar1Client = this.UISomeRandomCompanyWindow.UIMaintainCalendar1Window.UIItemWindow.uICalendar1Client;
        #endregion

        // Click 'Navigator' title bar
        Mouse.Click(uINavigatorTitleBar, new Point(241, 9));

        // Click 'objectdesc' text box
        Mouse.Click(uIObjectdescEdit, new Point(19, 11));

        // Click 'objectdesc' text box
        Mouse.Click(uIObjectdescEdit, new Point(39, 10));

        // Double-Click 'objectdesc' text box
        Mouse.DoubleClick(uIObjectdescEdit, new Point(37, 11));

        // Double-Click 'objectdesc' text box
        Mouse.DoubleClick(uIObjectdescEdit, new Point(20, 11));

        // Double-Click 'objectdesc' text box
        Mouse.DoubleClick(uIObjectdescEdit, new Point(42, 5));

        // Double-Click 'objectdesc' text box
        Mouse.DoubleClick(uIObjectdescEdit, new Point(61, 11));

        // Click 'Calendar [1]' client
        Mouse.Click(uICalendar1Client, new Point(632, 141));

        // Click 'Calendar [1]' client
        Mouse.Click(uICalendar1Client, new Point(671, 200));

        // Click 'Calendar [1]' client
        Mouse.Click(uICalendar1Client, new Point(675, 301));

        // Click 'Calendar [1]' client
        Mouse.Click(uICalendar1Client, new Point(686, 396));

        // Click 'Calendar [1]' client
        Mouse.Click(uICalendar1Client, new Point(686, 544));

        // Click 'Calendar [1]' client
        Mouse.Click(uICalendar1Client, new Point(478, 547));

        // Click 'Calendar [1]' client
        Mouse.Click(uICalendar1Client, new Point(579, 552));

        // Click 'Calendar [1]' client
        Mouse.Click(uICalendar1Client, new Point(579, 552));
    }
```

Notice the multiple instances of 'objectdesc' and 'Calendar [1]'. Every duplicate occurance is a different control, but the action recording isn't picking that up.

When I try to run the test I obviously get: Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.UITestControlNotFoundException: The playback failed to find the control with the given search properties.

I'm new to test automation in Visual Studio, so I'm not sure what options I have at this point. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For many controls the `new Point(x,y)` argument to `Mouse.Click()` is not needed but is provided for items that have two or more parts, eg a button that can be clicked but that also has a drop-down list. The (x,y) values in the code you show suggest that all that Coded UI is seeing is a big control, ie the whole calendar or the whole uIObjectdescEdit and not the fields within it.

I suspect the application uses some custom controls that do not support Coded UI. Find out from the developers how the application is written, what technologies (eg WPF, Windows Forms, MFC, etc) were used and what custom controls were used. Then check the answers against the compatibility lists on Microsoft's Coded UI web pages. If custom controls were used then you may need to repeat the question to the authors of those controls.

Comment: Thanks for the info Adrian. I'm not going to have access to the developers today, but I'll see how they coded the application. By all accounts they built the program over a decade ago. They've just been tacking on to it and updating it since then. I don't think they've done a full rebuild using new technologies recently - I think whatever they used, it's over a decade old.

Given that, it's probably unlikely that Coded UI/action recording will work, right?

Comment: Let me ask a follow up question - if I can't do automated testing vis a vis CodedUI tests, what options do I have? I've used automation tools like Vtask Studio in the past, but these aren't very robust tools would only serve in a pinch. I wouldn't want to put together a large suite of test with something like that. Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: @LuFaMa - I do not have any recommendations. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_GUI_testing_tools may give you some more ideas. Your comment about the program being old supports the theory in my answer. Talk to the developers, you may be fortunate and find that they purchased a library of controls for which there is a new version that properly supports Coded UI.

Comment: @LuFaMa most ui test automation hooks into the OS accessibility interfaces in some way. If the application is for sale in the EU, ask the developers how it meets modern accessibility requirements, then you'll know which of the automation tools to use. If it isn't accessible, then that may be something which should be addressed prior to test automation.